# Application of Spectral mapping Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Let $D\in B(H)$ be the diagonal operator with $De_n = d_ne_n$, where $(e_n)_n$ is an orthonormal basis.

Suppose $f: \sigma(D) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function. Show that $f(D)$ is still diagonal, i.e $f(D)e_n=f(d_n)e_n$.

I thought about using the spectral mapping theorem. If $p_n$ is a polynomial, then by Weierstrass, the continuous $f$ will be the limit. So we by the spectral mapping theorem, we have $\sigma(f(D)) = f(\sigma(D))$.

But I'm not sure how to construct the sequence of polynomials...

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you prove that an operator is diagonal if and only if it commutes with every one of the operators $E_n$, where $E_n$ is orthogonal projection onto the span of $e_n$?  If so, note that because $D$ commutes with each $E_n$, any polynomial in $D$ will commute with each $E_n$. Can you take it from there?  It kinda doesn't matter what the polynomials are.  The details may depend on how you have constructed the continuous functional calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instinct is a good one: Let $p_n$ be the sequence of polynomials given by Stone-Weirstrass with $\sup_{x\in \sigma(A)}|p_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Now it is obvious that for the polynomials, $p_n(A)$ are diagonal. So, for any $n$, and $i\ne j$,
$$
\langle e_j,p_n(A)e_i\rangle=0.
$$
So,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle e_j,p_n(A)e_i\rangle=\langle e_j,f(A)e_i\rangle=0
$$
where we have used that in fact $||p_n(A)-f(A)||\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ because of, for example, the spectral mapping.